# Guldun's intricate looking glass

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds

Spoiler for the waterlogged side quest follows:

> Guldun's intricate looking glass turns out to be a trick of the light. Is there a way to find one for him in the game or is it just one of those bitter endings?

Is there something to be found once the "Overflow basin is empty. Interior available. Minimal flood damage."?

Answer (score 2):

Threre is an optional part to this quest which results in a trophy, but it is not to do with this.

Once the water is drained and the interior is available go to the lowest level and find a door that leads to a room containing a simple water flow puzzle (your focus will help find where to look). Solving the puzzle will give the 'drained the flood' trophy.

Comment: I did this before fixing the control panel and getting the "Overflow basin is empty. Interior available. Minimal flood damage." message. So, either it refers to something else or it is a bug in the game. Either is possible. ☺

Comment: I don't think the order matters, I didn't get the trophy until the very end of the quest.